# mutual information entropy problem

Tags: information-theory, entropy

In mutual information we have: if $x$ and $y$ are independent then 
$p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$ and then $I(X;Y)=0$.

Do If $I (X;Y) = 0$ when $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily independent?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site.